# Sorting (names) using Merge Sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, merge

having problem sorting repeated Strings,

and here's my code..

i successfully sorted the first array but in the second (with repeated strings) it seems not in orderly output, can you help me to trace whats wrong in my code..

```
import java.util.*;

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] ClassOne = { "Kring", "Panda", "Soliel", "Darryl", "Chan", "Matang", "Jollibee.", "Inasal" };
        String[] ClassTwo = { "Minnie", "Kitty", "Madonna", "Miley", "Zoom-zoom", "Cristine", "Bubbles", "Ara", "Rose", "Maria" };
        String[] names = new String[ClassOne.length + ClassTwo.length];

        mergeSort(ClassOne);
        mergeSort(ClassTwo);

        merge(names, ClassOne, ClassTwo);

        mergeSort(names);
        //Arrays.sort(names);

        for (String ClassThree : names) {
            System.out.println(ClassThree);
        }
    }

    public static void mergeSort(String[] names) {
        if (names.length > 2) {
            String[] left = new String[names.length / 2];
            String[] right = new String[names.length - names.length / 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
                left[i] = names[i];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < right.length; i++) {
                right[i] = names[i + names.length / 2];
            }

            mergeSort(left);
            mergeSort(right);
            merge(names, left, right);
        }
    }

    public static void merge(String[] names, String[] left, String[] right) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (b >= right.length || (a < left.length && left[a].compareToIgnoreCase(right[b]) < 0)) {
                names[i] = left[a];
                a++;
            } else {
                names[i] = right[b];
                b++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and heres the output::

```
Ara
Chan
Cristine
Bubbles
Jollibee.
Inasal
Kring
Madonna
Matang
Miley
Minnie
Kitty
Panda
Rose
Maria
Soliel
Darryl
Zoom-zoom
```

...

Comment: I don't see the repeated strings.

Comment: i mean same first letter,(maria, madonna, miley...)

Comment: You can use [Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) which uses mergesort

Comment: yes yes, but i want to stick only in my own function...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
if (names.length > 2) {
```

with

```
if (names.length >= 2) {
```

output

```
Ara
Bubbles
Chan
Cristine
Darryl
Inasal
Jollibee.
Kitty
Kring
Madonna
Maria
Matang
Miley
Minnie
Panda
Rose
Soliel
Zoom-zoom
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change this:

```
if (names.length > 2)
```

to

```
if (names.length > 1)
```

`mergeSort` runs recursively spliting the array into two halves, then merges them and return back up the call chain. When the length of the array passed to `mergeSort` is <= 1 it considers the array sorted, this is called the **base case**.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just concatenate the two arrays (String ClassOne and ClassTwo) into one and then call a MergeSort on one array? Your process makes the program more ambiguous in my opinion.