# Merge Sorting HashTable pairs based on String key

Tags: java, sorting, hashtable

I'm writing a program that counts word occurrences in a text file and then prints them in alphabetical order. I have the counting part working correctly but I need to use a merge sort to get the words alphabetized. To that end, I wrote the following methods:

```
public static HashPair<String, Integer>[] mergeSort(HashPair<String, Integer>[] data)
    {
        HashPair<String, Integer>[] sortedData = null;
        if (data.length >= 2) {
            HashPair<String, Integer>[] left = new HashPair[data.length / 2];
            HashPair<String, Integer>[] right = new HashPair[data.length - data.length / 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
                if(data[i] != null)
                {
                    left[i] = data[i];
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < right.length; i++) {
                if(data[i + data.length / 2] != null)
                {
                    right[i] = data[i + data.length / 2];
                }
            }

            mergeSort(left);
            mergeSort(right);
            sortedData = merge(data, left, right);
        }
        return sortedData;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to merge the data back into one array
     * Based on code found at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795158/sorting-names-using-merge-sort
     * 
     * @param names
     * @param left
     * @param right
     */
    public static HashPair<String, Integer>[] merge(HashPair<String, Integer>[] data, HashPair<String, Integer>[] left, HashPair<String, Integer>[] right) 
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        {
            try
            {
                if (b >= right.length || (a < left.length && left[a].getFirst().compareToIgnoreCase(right[b].getFirst()) < 0)) 
                {
                    data[i] = left[a];
                    a++;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    data[i] = right[b];
                    b++;
                }
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

To call these methods in main and print out the table I use the following 3 lines

```
HashPair<String, Integer>[] unsortedData = wordTable.getData(); //Getting unsorted data to be sorted
HashPair<String, Integer>[] sortedData = mergeSort(unsortedData);
HashTable<String, Integer> sortedWordTable = new HashTable(sortedData);
sortedWordTable.dump(); //Printing all the words found with their respective counts
```

However, the words print unalphabetized as if the sort never ran and I cannot figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new HashTable with sortedData as a parameter they will not be in order. HashTables are used for efficiency not sorting. When elements are added they are hashed into the table in basically random order.

Find a different way to hold the sorted data than a HashTable. Like an array list.

Comment: No problem. HashTables are funky.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a TreeMap instead of a HashTable; in this case the words would already be sorted.  Each time you reach a new word you can just use the code:

```
  if(!map.containsKey(word)) map.put(word,0);
  map.put(word, map.get(word)+1);
```