# I am having an issue with implementing a Mergesort algorithm for String arrays in a separate Class

Tags: java, array-merge

I implemented this algorithm from another Stackoverflow question which should be working: [Sorting (names) using Merge Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795158/sorting-names-using-merge-sort)

As of now, this is the output I'm getting:
Apfel   Apfel   Banane  Limone  Banane

```
public class TestMergesort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] fruechte = new String[]{"Orange","Apfel","Zitrone","Limone","Banane"};
        Mergesorttwo.mergeSort(fruechte);

        for (int i = 0;i<fruechte.length;i++)
            System.out.print(fruechte[i]+"\t");
    }
}

public class Mergesorttwo {
    public static void mergeSort(String[] arr) {
        if (arr.length > 1) {
            String[] left = new String[arr.length / 2];
            String[] right = new String[arr.length - arr.length / 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
                left[i] = arr[i];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < right.length; i++) {
                right[i] = arr[i + arr.length / 2];
            }

            mergeSort(left);
            mergeSort(right);
            merge(arr, left, right);

        }
    }

        public static void merge(String[] arr, String[] left, String[] right){
            int l = 0;
            int r = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (l < right.length && r < left.length) {
                    if (r>= right.length || (l < left.length &&left[l].compareTo(right[r]) <= 0)) arr[i] = left[l++];
                    else arr[i] = right[r++];;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check your merge algorithm. That cannot be correct. Just Imagine, that it is called on an array with 2 elements so you have left and right as arrays with just 1 element.
l and r are 0. So inside first if, both checks are true and one item is assigned to the first element and l or r are increased.
Now the first if will no longer be triggered because l or r are 1. So the 2nd element of the array is unchanged.

So I would do the following checks:

```
        public static void merge(String[] arr, String[] left, String[] right){
        int l = 0;
        int r = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (l < left.length && r < right.length) {
                if (left[l].compareTo(right[r]) <= 0)
                    arr[i] = left[l++];
                else
                    arr[i] = right[r++];;
            } else if (l < left.length) {
                arr[i] = left[l++];
            } else {
                arr[i] = right[r++];
            }
        }
    }
```

So the checks are mainly: Are elements in left and right left? Then take the smallest value of left and right. If not elements in both are left, we check where elements are left and take the element of left or right side.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out my simple mistakes. I suppose I lost my concentration after spending too much time on another approach!